# Magento 2: How to move currency switcher

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, theme, currency

I'm fairly new to Magento 2 and I need guidance on how to move the currency switcher from the top-header-content and into the middle-header-content. I'm using the Claue theme.

I understand the that there is a move instruction that can be used in xml, but I have no idea in which xml file I would need to put this or if I should create a new xml file.

Underneath I have posted a couple of images that show what I am trying to achieve.

(I only have this project setup locally.)

[image]

[image]

Comment: I also have this problem. If you use a simple move as the other answer indicates, the switcher is no longer a dropdown menu, but is a list of all currencies.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use block move functionality with making some css tweak for adjust their place. For more reference go through [doc](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html)  , below is the example of code snippets you have to change elements & destination ,other elements.

```
<move element="currency" destination="header.panel" before="skip_to_content"/>
```

Comment: write the reason for giving negative vote.